# Horizontal lift and notation in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles

In the skript of my professor we define the horizontal lift in a fiber bundle as follows:
\begin{align}
^{hor}: TM\times_ME\rightarrow TE
\end{align}
with
\begin{align}
(Tpr\times \pi_{TE})\circ^{hor}=id_{TM\times_M E}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
\pi_{TE}: TE \rightarrow E
\end{align}
is the tangent bundle projection. With $TM\times_M E$ we usually denote the fiber product.
I have two questions:

1. If I understood correctly, the horizontal lift is a map that "lifts" tangent vectors of the base manifold to (horizontal) tangent vectors of the total space. So $^{hor}$ should be a map $^{hor}: TM \rightarrow TE$. Why did he define it as a map $^{hor}: TM\times_ME\rightarrow TE$?
2. Im not used to the notation $Tpr\times \pi_{TE}$ and I can't find any help in the skript, too. What could he mean with $\times$ between two maps here?

Comment: Regarding point (1), you need to know “which height to lift to”, that’s why you also need the $E$ factor. For point (2), simply note that applying $T(\text{pr})$ gives you something in $TM$, and applying $\pi_{TE}$ gives you something in $E$ (and both will be over the same base point in $M$). You now stick these two together in a tuple to get an element of $TM\times_ME$. Anyway, this is too condensed. See the first part of [Intuition behind connection 1-forms and Ehresmann connections](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4752169/568204) for more details (I call the map $L$ there, for ‘lifting’).